# create anonymous object via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a object:

```
public class Ticket
{
   public string EventName {get;set;}
   public string Count {get;set;}
   public string Price {get;set;}
   ... other properties;
}
```

For test:

```
var tickets = new List<Ticket>();
tickets.Add(new Ticket {EventName = "Test", TicketCount = 1, Price = 100});
tickets.Add(new Ticket { EventName = "Test", TicketCount = 2, Price = 200 });
tickets.Add(new Ticket { EventName = "Test2", TicketCount = 1, Price = 50 });
```

I want to get anonymous object  with following properties: `EventName, TicketCount, Price`
and "grouped" by event name.
For the example above the result must be:
anonymous object must contain two records:

```
EventName = Test, TicketCount = 3, Price = 300
EventName = Test2, TicketCount = 1, Price = 50
```

My not finished code:

```
var groupedByEvent = tickets.GroupBy(t => t.EventName);
var obj = new {EventName = seatsByEvent.Select(t=>t.Key), TicketCount = seatsByEvent.Sum(???)}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var result = tickets.GroupBy(t => t.EventName)
                    .Select(g  => new { 
                             EventName = g.Key, 
                             TicketCount = g.Sum(t => t.TicketCount), 
                             Price = g.Sum(t => t.Price)
                    });

foreach(var x in result)
     Console.WriteLine("EventName = {0}, TicketCount = {1}, Price = {2}"
                       , x.EventName , x.TicketCount , x.Price);
```

Answer (score 5):

First you have to set your POCO class right:

```
public class Ticket
{
  public string EventName {get;set;}
  public string Count {get;set;}
  public int Price {get;set;}
  public int TicketCount { get; set; }
}
```

`Price` has to be and int and also like the `TicketCount`, that's necessarily for the sum.

Then the linq query will look like this:

```
var events = tickets.GroupBy(t => t.EventName).Select(g => new 
{
  EventName = g.Key,
  TicketCount = g.Sum(t => t.TicketCount),
  Price = g.Sum(t => t.Price)
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var groupedByEvent = tickets.GroupBy(t => t.EventName);

var obj = groupByEvent.Select(group => new {
   EventName = group._Key,
   TicketCount = group.Sum(x => x.TicketCount),
   Price = group.Sum(x => x.Price)
});
```